# Number of ways of arranging $56$ balls in $4$ urns with different residues modulo $6$ in each urn.

Tags: combinatorics

I want to arrange $56$ identical balls into $4$ distinct urns, witht the following requirements. Letting $x_n$ be the number of balls in the $n^\text{th}$ urn,

- ${x_i\gt 0}$
- ${6\nmid x_i - x_j}$.

**My work**:
This appears as a standard stars and bars problem, so:
$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4 = 56$$ or setting $b_i=x_i-1$
$$b_1+b_2+b_3+b_4=52$$ such that $b_i \geq 0$. Hence the number of ways in which the first constraint is satisfied is $55\choose{3}$ = $26235$. But I am unsure how to work with the second constraint.

My idea is we find the number of ways in which the difference of balls in any two urns is $6k$ and use the Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion to subtract them from 26235 but this appears tedious.

I feel like generating functions may be useful, so any approach using them is also welcome. (I haven’t formally started with them)

Comment: There are only $6$ residues $\pmod 6$ and we can't have any two $x_i$ in the same class.  Thus you need to pick the $4$ classes which are represented and work from there.  Noting that, if $x_i\equiv r_i\pmod 6$ you can start by putting $r_i$ balls in (put in $6$ if $r_i=0$) and what's left is a multiple of $6$.

Comment: The remainders of each bin when divided by 6 will be $0,1,2,5$, or will be $0,1,3,4$ or will be $2,3,4,5$.  Convince yourself there are no others.  This is because we must have each bin with a distinct remainder and the sum of all bins have the same remainder as 56 mod 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is pointed out in the comments, in order for the second condition to be fulfilled, it is easy to show that all $x_i$'s (and therefore $b_i$'s) need to have distinct remainders modulo 6. Since the $b_i$ satisfy

$$b_1+b_2+b_3+b_4=52$$

we need to ensure that the sum of remainders $0\leq r_i< 6: b_i=6k_i+r_i$ is correct modulo 6, in other words they must satisfy

$$r_1+r_2+r_3+r_4=4 (\text{mod}~ 6)$$

and the only possible distinct tetrads of numbers satisfying this are

$$(0,1,4,5), (0,2,3,5), (1,2,3,4)$$

For each of those tetrads, there are 4! permutations of it that we have to take into account. Now, substituting back into the equation for $b_i$ we obtain

$$k_1+k_2+k_3+k_4=7$$

which can now be counted using stars and bars. The final answer is

$$3\times 4!\times {10\choose 3}=8640$$

which can be readily verified by a brute force search in Mathematica.

```
starsbars[M_, 1] := {M}
starsbars[M_, k_] := Module[{next},
next = {};
Do[
next = 
   Append[next, Flatten@{#, idx} & /@ starsbars[M - idx, k - 1 ]];
, {idx, 0, M}];
next = Flatten[next, 1]
];

temp = starsbars[52, 4];
redstars = {};
Do[
check = (Tally[Table[Mod[temp[[i, n]], 6], {n, 1, 4}]])[[;; , 2]];
If[Product[check[[j]], {j, 1, Length[check]}] == 1, 
redstars = Append[redstars, temp[[i]]];]
, {i, 1, Length@temp}]

redstars // Length

8640
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm confused. The problem demands all $x_i>0$ right? So that surely means none of the urns can be empty?

Comment: None of the urns are supposed to be empty, and the final answer is also $4!\cdot360$.

Comment: @DinosaurEgg Good catch, I totally missed that.  I have therefore deleted my comments following the posting and deleted my comments following your answer.